# SQL/SSMS - partial data move from one table to another with two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2014

Ok...I've looked around and haven't found anything that helps me resolve my specific issue. I have a table with contents that I am trying to move (table1) to an existing table (table2) into newly created columns.
table1:

```
CNTC_COMM_TYP_ID    CNTC_COMM_VAL   CNTC_ID COMM_TYP_ID
14                  406-444-1104        4       1
15                  406-443-2127        4       4
16                  ssands@foo.bar      4       3
17                  406-338-2181       16       1
18                  406-338-7127       16       4
```

table2:

```
CNTC_ID CNTC_NM     ST_ENTY_ID  TRBL_ID WorkPhone   CellPhone   Email   Fax
1      Poole, Andy      10     NULL    NULL         NULL    NULL    NULL
2      Goodwin, Annie NULL        5    NULL         NULL    NULL    NULL
```

The issue that I am having trouble with is separating the values into the appropriate column. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
WHERE table1.CNTC_ID = table2.CNTC_ID
```

and:

```
IF (GAIN_CNTC_COMM_TYP.CNTC_TYP_ID= 1) {
    SET WorkPhone = table1.CNTC_COMM_VAL
}
ELSE IF (table1.CNTC_TYP_ID= 2) {
    SET CellPhone = table1.CNTC_COMM_VAL
}
ELSE IF (table1.CNTC_TYP_ID= 3) {
    SET Email = table1.CNTC_COMM_VAL
}
ELSE IF (table1.CNTC_TYP_ID = 4)
    SET Fax = GAIN_CNTC_COMM_TYP.CNTC_COMM_VAL
}
```

I've tried putting together a CASE WHEN in SQL, but I'm struggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pivot` the data in `table1` and then update `table2`

```
;with cte as
(
select  CNTC_ID,
        WorkPhone=max(case when COMM_TYP_ID = 1 then CNTC_COMM_VAL end),
        CellPhone=max(case when COMM_TYP_ID = 2 then CNTC_COMM_VAL end),
        Email=max(case when COMM_TYP_ID = 3 then CNTC_COMM_VAL end),
        Fax=max(case when COMM_TYP_ID = 4 then CNTC_COMM_VAL end)
From Yourtable
Group by CNTC_ID
)
UPDATE t2
SET    WorkPhone = c.WorkPhone,
       CellPhone = c.CellPhone,
       Email = c.Email,
       Fax = c.Fax
FROM   table2 t2
       JOIN cte c
         ON t2.CNTC_ID = c.CNTC_ID
```

Comment: Just curious, why the CTE? Couldn't you have just put the case statements in the update or is that not best practice?

Comment: we cannot add those case statements in set clause directly.. instead of cte you can use derived table.. but cte looks more readable

Comment: I just built it all out myself and now I understand. @Prdp thanks.

Comment: @Prdp - Thank you so much! Worked perfectly. I've never used CTE before...my brain has just grown a size.